# how to read the resource url of rdf:range using owlready2 library in python?

Tags: rdf, dbpedia, rdfs, owlready

I used dbpedia.owl file and load the ontology with `owlready2` library. I want to know how can I access the `rdf:resource` under `rdfs:domain` tag. Their docs have no any clue to do this. Following shows current code status.

```
from owlready2 import *

# ===== Loading dbpedia.owl =========
onto_path.append("../")
onto = get_ontology("dbpedia.owl")
onto.load()

propertyDict = {}

propertiesGen = onto.properties()

for ontoProperty in propertiesGen:
    if len(ontoProperty.range) == 0:
        print(ontoProperty)
```

Is there a way to access like `ontoProperty.range.resource`? But that does not work. Following section in `owl` file shows the correspondence to `ontoProperty`.
Really appreciate your answers and suggestions.

```
<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/nationalRanking">
   <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property"/>
   <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">national ranking</rdfs:label>
   <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/EducationalInstitution"/>
   <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#positiveInteger"/><prov:wasDerivedFrom rdf:resource="http://mappings.dbpedia.org/index.php/OntologyProperty:nationalRanking"/>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>
```

Comment: I don't know what you want with the `rdf:resource` or `.resource` - that is just part of the RDF/XML serialization of RDF and OWL data but has no dedicated meaning in OWL. it is just `ontoProperty.domain` and the value is always a list given that a property can have multiple domains.

Comment: I need to find out ontology properties that have ranges as float or int, I know their range as http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#positiveInteger. But I can't read them because of XML/OWL file has base url to dbpedia.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. In your question you have been asking how to get domain and/or range of properties. And I told you how to do. So what is the problem with iterating over the properties and check if the range equals the range you're looking for?

Comment: and this sentence doesn't make any sense: *"But I can't read them because of XML/OWL file has base url to dbpedia."* - the file is in RDF/XML syntax and you can get everything that is inside the file

Comment: Simply I'm asking how to read the url of range as an example "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/nationalRanking". Finally I get it done by scraping the file using `beutifulsoup` instead of `owlready2`.

Comment: when I do `for ontoProperty in propertiesGen:
    print(str(ontoProperty) + ":" + str(ontoProperty.range))` I get, among others, `dbpedia.nationalRanking:[<class 'int'>]`. And given this list of [supported datatypes](https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/properties.html#data-property), I guess the `xsd:positiveInteger` info might be lost during parsing. It's better to ask the devs

Comment: Yeah, That's why guess the cause of this issue as `baseUrl` has been set to `dbpedia.org` not to `www.w3.org`.